# How to get user.field value in node.twig

Tags: 8, theming

I have a `field_author` with different values `expert, moderator or contributor`

For get this custom USER field in node.twig i using next function

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
                  $variables['author'] = $node->getOwner()->field_fname->value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then `{{ author }}` in node.twig

How to get vlue of this field? For example `{{ author.0 or author.1 or author.3}}`?

Thanl you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `field_fname` is a custom field added to users? if so what is the field type (select or textfield) and if it is a select how many values accept limited or unlimited values?

anyway you can try this for checkbox list
Try this

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $variables['author'] = $node->getOwner()->get('field_fname')->getValue();
  } 
}
```

node.twig:

```
{% if author.0.target_id == "expert" %}
<h1>Hello Expert<h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, `field_fname` is a custom field added to users. Field type is textfield (List) with checkboxes. You can select only one value.

Comment: See the Updates on my answer

Comment: Not works. As I understand the problem is here `$variables['author'] = $node->getOwner()->get('field_fname')->getValue();`

Comment: Not really it works perfectlly you cant test it with the field roles of user change it with   `$variables['author'] = $node->getOwner()->get('roles')->getValue();` you will get the first selected role.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with field_name. Works perfect! Thank you a lot! Now I want to print condition it Twig `{{ if author.0.target_id is expert }} Some text {{ endif }}`. How to do this?

Comment: see my answer updates.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! You helped me a LOT!

Comment: you're welcome bro! ;)

Comment: In `hook_preprocess_node()`, there is no need to use `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')` to get the node object, since it is already passed in the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using variable `node`

Get `user.name`

```
{{ node.uid.entity.name.value }}
```